# Android billing 5.0.0 sdk compatibility

Tags: android, compatibility, in-app-billing, android-billing, android-version

I have migrated my app to the 5.0.0 version of the billing library, as it is adviced. However, I've found that it's not working properly on old devices in which the old library did work. I've tested it on Android 7 (Nougat API 24), Android 9 (Pie API 28) and Android 12 (S API 31). The only one in which it's not working it's on the Nougat one and I would like to know if it's somewhere in the documentation reported which API levels are supported and which don't.

The "error" I'm getting is `SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE` as response code when calling `queryProductDetailsAsync`.

I'm also assuming it's a sdk version issue, as I can't find other cause (the Play Store is updated, the wifi is on and my Google account logged in).

Answer (score 0):

Something must be misconfigured in the phone. I tested on an Android 6 and it worked, so I tried completely restoring my Android 7. Now it works.

However, I still wonder why the old library worked and the new one didn't.